# prove or disprove: if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n^2$ converges

Tags: calculus

if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n^2$ converges

I think I'm supposed to disprove it, but i can't think of anything.
non of the usual stuff disproved it.

I know that becuase $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges $a_n\to0$, and that means that $a_n^2\to0$. Also, assuming that the sequence does not contain $i$, $a_n^2$ must be positive. The only thing preventing me to use Leibniz's Test is that I don't know for sure that $a_n^2$ is monotonically decreasing.

Things I tried to disprove it:

Alternating sequences, with or without $i$

Engineering a sequence that is made from even/odd sub-sequences

$a_n$ as a series itself

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Note that $|a_n|$ is eventually $<1$ and so, $|a_n^2| \le |a_n|$. Can you conclude?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani: $\sum a_n$ is not absolutely convergent. So your comment does not help.

Comment: hint: consider $a_{2k - 1} = 0$ and $a_{2k} = (-1)^k b_k$ such that $b_k$ is decreasing and $\sum_k b_k^2$ is infinite.

Comment: @user251257: yes, you correct. I was implicitly thinking that $a_n \ge 0$.

Comment: Since I can't edit my original comment anymore, I shall keep it up and point out that the result would be true if $(a_n)$ does not change sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_{2n}=(-1)^n/(\sqrt n +1), a_{2n+1}=0$ gives a counterxample as $\sum a_n$ converges, but $\sum (-1)^na_n^2$ diverges

Comment: Is there a special reason for putting $\sqrt{n}+1$ an not just $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: This way we allow $n=0$ without expliciting it (the OP series started at $a_0$) - of course it doesn't matter except that you need to define $a_0$ separately otherwise

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to be of help